# Custom UISlider Not able to set the minimum track color properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uislider

I've subclassed UISlider and increased the width by doing this:

```
-(CGRect)trackRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {

bounds.size.height = 50;
return bounds;

}
```

And changed the thumb image:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
// Drawing code
[self setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_circle"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

But this is happening:

[image][image]

The minimum track image starts from the center. I want to make it start from the thumb end. So initially, till the thumb it should be blue and when I drag it till the end the whole slider should be blue but at the end of the slider, the slider is not curved. It has got sharped edges. What should I do to get this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't find much help so I made my own custom one instead. It's also available on GitHub. https://github.com/bhavukjain1/SlideToActionSlideriOS

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the following properties?

```
UIImage *minImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"slider_minimum.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 0)];
UIImage *maxImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"slider_maximum.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 5)];
UIImage *thumbImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sliderhandle.png"];

[[UISlider appearance] setMaximumTrackImage:maxImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[UISlider appearance] setMinimumTrackImage:minImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[UISlider appearance] setThumbImage:thumbImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

}

if so, take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.getappninja.com/blog/how-to-make-a-custom-uislider) of how to create a custom slider, it comes with a sample project, may be it's easier for you to find your error by comparing your implementation against a working one.

Comment: I don't have slider image. I just have thumb image and I'm using colors for minimum and maximum track color.

Comment: Then, I agree with a guy from a similar stack overflow answer that thinks that this happens because the round end is generated by the UISlider natively and assumes that the thumb image will cover the end at extreme positions so it will not redraw it, a workaround will be to use a rounded image for the min and max tracks.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the rectangular corners issue, in drawRect

```
self.layer.cornerRadius = 25;
self.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

To show the correct image while dragging, you need to set this as well:

```
[self setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_circle"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```